# insert from radio button to MS access database by coldfusion

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, radio-button

I'm trying to insert values from radio buttons to database. Below is my js code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < document.form.repnumber.value; i++)
    {
            newInnerHTML = newInnerHTML +'Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"rep' +(i+1) +'\" value=\"\" size=\"50\">*<br> ';
            newInnerHTML = newInnerHTML +'Email:<input type=\"text\" name=\"rep' +(i+1) +'\email" value=\"\" size=\"60\"><br> ';
            newInnerHTML = newInnerHTML +'UI Alum? <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"rep' +(i+1) +'\alumn" value=\"alumn\" ><br> ';
            newInnerHTML = newInnerHTML +'<b>Break-Out Sessions</b>: *<br>';
            newInnerHTML = newInnerHTML +'New Recruiters <input type=\"radio\" name=\"rep' +(i+1) +'\sessions" value=\"1\" checked=\"checked\"><br>';
            newInnerHTML = newInnerHTML +'Seasoned Recruiters <input type=\"radio\" name=\"rep' +(i+1) +'\sessions" value=\"2\"><br>';
            newInnerHTML = newInnerHTML +'Community Partners <input type=\"radio\" name=\"rep' +(i+1) +'\sessions" value=\"3\"><br><br>';
    }
```

And for the action page, the code is just like

```
insert  into tablename(rep1sessions ...) values (#rep1sessions#...)
```

But for now, in my database the 'sessions' column is only showing 0 or -1 for number/text, checked/unchecked for yes/no. 
My goal is just to show 1,2,3 three different values in the column. Any ideas?

Comment: By "showing" do you mean the results of a direct query ie `SELECT rep1sessions FROM tableName` are returning 0 and 1 instead of "1,2,3"? If so, dump the FORM scope on the action page to verify the form fields contain "1,2 or 3". Also, dump the query to see the generated sql.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you need to think about your database structure.

You definitely don't want to be storing comma delimited lists in a column in any database. Nor do you want to have column names in the form "mycolumnx" where x is a number.

In terms of how you process dynamic form fields like this its really very easy. All variables are in structures. This includes scopes such as form and url.

Structures and their keys can be accessed as associative arrays. This means that form.rep1session can be accessed as form["rep1session"] 
Extrapolating this out you can access your form variables in a loop replacing the number with a variable eg.  form["rep"& i& "session"]

After that you simply need to store your values in an appropriate relational database structure.

Comment: I could be wrong, but as each field name includes a counter variable I do not think they are storing lists (or I certainly hope not :). But agreed about avoiding the `columnX` naming convention for tables. Storing similar properties in rows, rather than columns, is generally a better approach. @Zhecheng - can you clarify?